# Не нашёл АPI (can-utils) как быть?

Tags: linux, c, демон

В общем столкнулся с задачей, "перекинуть" одну программу на linux. Она не является "нижайшей" и по сути что бы могла полноценно работать ей требуется работать через [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils).

Я решил пойти "стандартным" путём, подключить заголовочный файл от [can-utils-а](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) и вызывать её API функции в своей программе. В общем всё просто и понятно. **НО в can-utils НЕТ API** (вот это поворот).

В общем по сути я как понял [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils) это конгломерат демонов и я совсем не понял как сними работать, Поиск в интернете не дал мне результатов.

Как надо действовать ?? Что я упускаю ??

Comment: для начала, чтобы не ломать глаза, проект называется просто `can-utils`, а «**master**» — это `git`-ветка, по сути просто «версия»... во-вторых, да — это просто набор консольных утилит и пара шлюзов... «как быть» — вопрос звучит слишком обще... для начала чётко сформулируй, что ты хочешь сделать, желательно одну простую, но чётко определённую задачу, затем определи, что  у тебя уже есть, учитывая специфику, какие аппаратные средства, работают ли они корректно и прочее...

Comment: @Fat-Zer верно, вот пример `system "cansend can0 \'202#55aa\' "` можно было бы   подключить заголовочный файл и тем самым избавиться от system, (точнее так можно, но я не знаю как это сделать , какой заголовочный подключить и как его найти ) ?

Answer (score 1):

Никакой промежуточной библиотеки между `can-utils` и ядром нет — всё работает напрямую через API сокетов аналогично обычным сетевым tcp/udp. Основную опорную документацию по этому вопросу можно найти в составе [ядра](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt). Соответственно некоторые полезные константы и структуры объявлены в `<linux/can.h>` и прочих хедерах `linux/can/*`. Эти файлы являются частью API linux и обычно поставляются в пакете `linux-headers` (обычно уже установлен, если установлена прочая dev-мишура).

В качестве примеров кода можно использовать вышеупомянутую документацию или сам can-utils.

> вот пример system "cansend can0 \'202#55aa\' " можно было бы подключить заголовочный файл и тем самым избавиться от system

[`cansend`](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/cansend.c) — уже сам по себе минимальный пример, но, наглядности ради, аналогичный код на Си, опуская все проверки, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <linux/can.h>

// ...

// создание can-сокета
int s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW);

// задание структуры связанной can-интерфейс
struct ifreq ifr = {.name = "can0"};
ifr.ifr_ifindex = if_nametoindex(ifr.ifr_name);

// связывание сокета с конкретным адресом
struct sockaddr_can addr; 
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

// отправка сетевого кадра
struct canfd_frame frame = {.can_id=0x202, .len=2, .flags=0, .data={0x55,0xaa}};
write(s, &frame, offsetof(struct canfd_frame,data) + frame.len);
```

Comment: тут скорость не прописана и код не оплавляет сообщение, а  скорость  где писать, я так и не понял, но сижу читаю :(

Comment: @timob256, скорость прописывается в настройках интерфейса при его поднятии, из твоего же соседнего самоответа: `ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000`...

Comment: Да это руками через консоль , а я хочу через код но в [тут](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) просто не нашёл :(

Comment: @timob256, через голые системные вызовы это всё относительно геморройно — если кратко, то для конфигурации интерфейсов общение с ядром производится через специальные netlink-сокеты см. `man 7 netlink`, соответственно нужно будет создать такой и сформировать специальное сообщение, за деталями я бы посоветовал изучить исходники iproute2 т.к. хорошей документации я по этому поводу не видел...

Comment: но конфигурация сетевого интерфейса — это не то что делается приложением каждый раз, так что подразумевается, что администратор пропишет соответствующую строчку в один из стартовых скриптов — для «больших» сетевых интерфейсов вроде Ethernet/IP этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: странно но почему-то не работает 0_о, при этом ошибку также не пишет.

Comment: @timob256, не забыл на все вызовы добавить контроль ошибок? ещё у меня есть подозрение, что во `write` надо писать всю структуру размером `sizeof(struct canfd_frame)`, а не только её содержательную часть...