# передал адрес переменной в функцию в виде ссылки

Tags: c

передал адрес переменной в функцию в виде ссылки. Но почемуто пишет ошибку ;_;

вот структура :

```
/**
 * struct canfd_frame - CAN flexible data rate frame structure
 * @can_id: CAN ID of the frame and CAN_*_FLAG flags, see canid_t definition
 * @len:    frame payload length in byte (0 .. CANFD_MAX_DLEN)
 * @flags:  additional flags for CAN FD
 * @__res0: reserved / padding
 * @__res1: reserved / padding
 * @data:   CAN FD frame payload (up to CANFD_MAX_DLEN byte)
 */
struct canfd_frame {
    canid_t can_id;  /* 32 bit CAN_ID + EFF/RTR/ERR flags */
    __u8    len;     /* frame payload length in byte */
    __u8    flags;   /* additional flags for CAN FD */
    __u8    __res0;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    __res1;  /* reserved / padding */
    __u8    data[CANFD_MAX_DLEN] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
};
```

вот так

```
struct canfd_frame frame; // отправка сообщений
struct canfd_frame frame_read; // приём сообщений

if(init_R2DIO(&frame, &s, &frame_read) == true )
{
   ... 
}


bool init_R2DIO(struct canfd_frame *frame, int *s, struct canfd_frame *frame_read)
{
    frame->can_id=0x000; frame->len=2; frame->flags=0; frame->data={0x80,0x08};
    write(s, &frame, offsetof(struct canfd_frame, data) + frame->len);
....
```

ошибка на строку `frame->can_id=0x000; frame->len=2; frame->flags=0; frame->data={0x80,0x08};`

> ошибка: expected expression before ‘{’ token
>        frame->can_id=0x000; frame->len=2; frame->flags=0; frame->data={0x80,0x08};

Что не так я не могу понять.

Comment: Что такое `struct canfd_frame`? Почему в вопросе не приведено объявление этого типа? Что такое `frame->data={0x80,0x08};`? С чего вы взяли, что так можно делать?

Comment: @AnT а почему [тут сработало ??](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/959423/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%88%d1%91%d0%bb-%d0%90pi-can-utils-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c)

Comment: Что именно "тут сработало"? У вас там нет никакого *присваивания*, а используется *инициализация*. Инициализация и присваивание - это совершенно разные вещи, работающие по совершенно разным правилам.

Comment: И возьмите в привычку писать каждый statement на отдельной строчке. Тогда компилятор сможет вам показать, какой именно statement вызывает ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В языке С нет и никогда не было такого синтаксиса

```
frame->data={0x80,0x08};
```

`frame->data` - это массив. В С нет присваивания массивов.

В вашем случае можно "выкрутиться" через использование составных литералов

```
*frame = (struct canfd_frame) { .len = 2, .data = {0x80, 0x08} };
```

Но в общем случае язык С не поддерживает присваивание массивов.

Comment: А как тогда с структурами работать ??

Comment: @timob256: Не понял. В чем вы видите проблемы в работе со структурами??? В вашем примере проблема не имеет никакого отношения к структуре. Проблема именно в работе с массивом внутри структуры.